# apache "Options Indexes" working localhost but not with public DNS name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, kubernetes, devops

I have a Kubernetes cluster and a very basic container. I am trying to access it through the internet and the task is very simple, I just need to list the index of the directory. Here is my basic virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 Alias /docs /mnt/nfs
 <Directory /mnt/nfs>
  DAV Off
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I use the service or pods with the kubectl port-forward option, it is working as expected and my files are listing with xyz.com/docs. However, when I try to access the pod via ingress through my FQDN, it gives me a 404 error. When I access a test.txt file that is inside the folder, I can see the content of the file but it is not listing the indexes like it is working with the port-forwarding option. so in short i can reach pod and access the files but can not list them with autoindex module and with same pod i am able to list index with kubectl port-forwarding option

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webdav-app
  namespace: testing1
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
    #cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - webdav.xyz.com
      secretName: webdav-app-certificate
  rules:
    - host: webdav.xyz.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: webdav-app
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: In your port-forward test, did you provide a `-H "host: webdav.xyz.com"` to more closely replicate the VirtualHost part? Did you already increase the apache logging to see what it thinks is going on?

Comment: Yes with -H i tried Curl and it seems giving me the expected result with no 404. I believe the issue is with Ingress. the way ingress communicates with the service. which I want to understand with some expert help like yourself. 
Because when I delete the service and pods Ingress gives me the same 404 page not found. error as described earlier even with the pods running. so the error is coming from ingress, i check the logs of traefikv2 ingress but there is nothing in the logs like 404. i am not sure where can i look for the missing piece of puzzle.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect the traefik logs to be impactful, I meant the Apache logs since it is the one that is ignoring your VirtualHost configuration, AIUI. Anyway, you may get more help by [editing your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1129208/edit) and *showing* the results of your debugging, since words are just works but logs are life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution for me was a workaround. I noticed that the "webroot" folder (/var/www/html) could be accessed in the same way I wanted to access the WebDAV folder (e.g., xyz.com/doc). So, I created a symlink at the root folder as /var/www/html/doc, and the doc symlink is pointing to the required doc folder. The option FollowSymLinks is also enabled in the config, which allowed it to work for me.

However, I am still not sure why it works in this way with FQDN.